# Choosing appropriate method using pattern matching in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pattern-matching

Currently am doing a college project in C# which includes conversion of one form of  code to another form of code, which involves choosing appropriate method/function from many methods available. The problem here is, to implement this using any pattern matching techniques rather then using many IF ELSE statements.

For now I have achieved this using nested IF ELSE statements which fills the whole program and looks like childish code on completion.

Current Implementation :--

Input:

```
//stored in list<string>
get(3 int)      //type1
get(int:a,b,c)  //type2
get(name)       //type3
//list passed to ProcessGET method
```

Using if else :

```
public string ProcessGET(List<string> inputData)
{
      foreach(var item in inputData)
      { 
         if (inputData.item.Split('(')[1].Split(')')[0].Contains(':'))
         {
            return Type2 result;
         }
         else if (!inputData.item.Split('(')[1].Split(')')[0].Contains(':') && Convert.ToInt32(inputData.item.Split('(')[1].Split(')')[0].Split(' ')[0])>0)
         {
            return Type1 result;
         }
         else
         {
            return Type3 result;
         }
      }   
}
```

How I wanted this to be is something like this,

```
/stored in list<string>
get(3 int)      //type1
get(int:a,b,c)  //type2
get(name)       //type3
//list passed to ProcessGET method


public string ProcessGET(List<string> inputData)
{
      foreach(var itm in inputData)
      { 
        // call appropriate method(itm) based on type using some pattern matching techniques
      }   
}

string Method1(var data)
{
    return result for type1;  
}   
string Method2(var data)
{
    return result for type2;  
}
string Method3(var data)
{
    return result for type3;  
}
```

Normally my program does mostly this kind of work for various types of input keywords like 'get','output','declare' etc etc etc... where  Get is transformed  to Scanf statements,output to printf statements and so on.
In such case if i use the IF ELSE, my project is full of If else statements.

As i just started to learn C#, I don't know if such thing exists(googled but didn't found what i was looking for), so any help regarding this problem will be very help(use)ful in further development.

Many Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you show us the actual code you've got? `function for Type3(var data)` isn't valid C#. I'm having a very hard time what you mean by `get(3 int)` as well. Are you talking about overloading?

Comment: `dynamic` keyword as a return type allows you to return arbitrary values. You can then check the type of what you returned with the `typeof` operator, maybe try digging into that materia and see if you can make use of it in your case. (`public dynamic ProcessGET()` could then return `Type1`, `Type2` and `Type3` objects without issues.)

Comment: @Rob - those get() input methods are my own custom syntax.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt - Sorry if I didn't mean correctly. Actually I always return string values from all methods.

Comment: A better way to transform code is to build (or use an existing) *parser* which builds an *abstract syntax tree* in memory and then transform that to the chosen output using the *'visitor pattern'* over the syntax tree. That may be beyond this project but it would be worth reading up on those concepts to understand better approaches to the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another general approach to this problem is to introduce an interface, say `IMatcher`. The interface has one method `Match` that returns either your type or maybe the fully transformed line.

You create multiple classes that implement `IMatcher`.

Your main loop then becomes:

```
var matchers = new [] { new MatcherA(), new MatcherB(), ... };

foreach (string line in input)
  foreach (matcher in matchers)
  {
     var match = matcher.Match(line);
     if (match != null) return match;
  }
```

No more big if statement. Each matcher has its own small class and you can write unit tests for each.  Also, use RegEx to make your matchers simpler.

Comment: Yeah, this reduces.Will try using this concept. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'll leave some suggestions here over which you can have a look at. Here's some basic code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace TestStuff
{
    class Program
    {
        //Input string should be of the form "<type>:<index>"
        static dynamic GiveMeSomethingDynamic(string someInput)
        {
            /* predefined arrays sothat we can return something */
            string[] _storedStrings = { "Word 1", "word 2", "word 3" };
            int[] _storedInts = { 1, 2, 3 };
            float[] _storedFloats = { 3.14f, 2.71f, 42.123f };

            /* Parse the input command (stringly typed functions are bad, I know.) */
            string[] splitted = someInput.Split(':');
            string wantedType = splitted[0];
            int index = int.Parse(splitted[1]);

            /* Decide what to return base on that argument */
            switch (wantedType)
            {
                case "int":
                    return _storedInts[index];
                case "string":
                    return _storedStrings[index];
                case "float":
                    return _storedFloats[index];

                //Nothing matched? return null
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /* get some return values */
            dynamic firstOutput = GiveMeSomethingDynamic("string:0");
            dynamic secondOutput = GiveMeSomethingDynamic("int:1");
            dynamic thirdOutput = GiveMeSomethingDynamic("float:2");

            /* Display the returned objects and their type using reflection */
            Console.WriteLine("Displaying returned objects.\n" +
                              "Object 1: {0}\t(Type: {1})\n" +
                              "Object 2: {2}\t\t(Type: {3})\n" +
                              "Object 3: {4}\t\t(Type: {5})\n",
                              firstOutput, firstOutput.GetType(),
                              secondOutput, secondOutput.GetType(),
                              thirdOutput, thirdOutput.GetType());

            /* Act on the type of a object. This works for *all* C# objects, not just dynamic ones. */
            if (firstOutput is string)
            {
                //This was a string! Give it to a method which needs a string
                var firstOutputString = firstOutput as string; //Cast it. the "as" casting returns null if it couldn't be casted.
                Console.WriteLine("Detected string output.");
                Console.WriteLine(firstOutputString.Substring(0, 4));
            }

            //Another test with reflection. 
            Console.WriteLine();

            //The list of objects we want to do something with
            string[] values = { "string:abcdef", "int:12", "float:3.14" };
            foreach(var value in values)
            {
                /* Parse the type */
                string[] parsed = value.Split(':');
                string _type = parsed[0];
                string _argument = parsed[1];

                switch (_type)
                {
                    case "string":
                        //This is a string.
                        string _stringArgument = _argument as string;
                        Method1(_stringArgument);
                        break;
                    case "int":
                        //Do something with this int
                        int _intArgument = int.Parse(_argument);
                        Method2(_intArgument);
                        break;
                    case "float":
                        float _floatArgument = float.Parse(_argument);
                        Method3(_floatArgument);
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Unrecognized value type \"{0}\"!", _type);
                        break;
                }

            }


            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void Method1(string s) => Console.WriteLine("String Function called with argument \"{0}\"", s);
        public static void Method2(int i) => Console.WriteLine("int Function called with argument {0}", i);
        public static void Method3(float f) => Console.WriteLine("float Function called with argument {0}", f);
    }
}
```

The first approach, given by the function `GiveMeSomethingDynamic()` relies on the `dynamic` keyword, which can **return** arbitrary types. Depending on the input string, it can return a `string`, an `int` or a `float`. The method is called in the `Main()` function and the type of the returned objects is checked with e.g. `firstOutput is string` (the `is` operator`). It could have also been done with`if( firstOutput.GetType() == typeof(string))`.

The second approach would be a classical "parse and cast" technique. We parse an input string of the format `<type>:<value>`, then call different functions with the converted or parsed arguments. This is maybe what you want.

There's also a "hacky" way **giving** a function arbitrary types. There, you can just the `dynamic` keyword on an input argument, as in

```
 public dynamic superDynamic(dynamic inputVar) 
 {
    //Figure out the type of that object
    //return something dynamic
 }
```

The "oldschool" approach (not using `dynamic`) would be to only pass `object` types into each function, but the parsing is equivalent (`if(someArgument.GetType() == typeof(string))`...).

Hope this gives you some ideas on how to parse these strings, cast them to different types and call different functions with it.

Comment: Thanks for providing lot of helpful additional information. Will figure out if I can be able to use those dynamic type

Answer (score 1):

So the types are stored as strings in a list, right? And you want to call a different function based on the value of the string?

Here's how I would finish your code:

1. Create an interface:

   ```
   public interface IMyType 
           {
               string Result(); 
               string Input {get; set;}

           }
   ```

   2. and three classes which implement it:

      ```
       public class Type1 : IMyType
          {
              public string Result()
              {
                  // do something
              }
              public string Input {get; set;}


          }
      ```

      (repeat for Type2 and Type3)

3.then create a method which returns one of these three types
based on pattern matching your string input

```
    public IMyType GetAppropriateType(string input)
    { 
    if (inputData.item.Split('(')[1].Split(')')[0].Contains(':'))
             {
                return new Type2 {Input = input};
             }
    //etc
    }

    public string ProcessGET(List<string> inputData)
    {
          foreach(var itm in inputData)
          { 
             IMyType type = GetAppropriateType(itm);
             type.Result();

          }   
    }
```

Probably worth looking at regex for your string matching too

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I think, in no way this method reduces the usage of number of 'IF' Statements when compared to direct usage of 'IF ELSE' statements, but it will help in hiding the large use of 'IF' statements in deep ground. The 3 condition checking statements(IF, IF ELSE, ELSE) inside the foreach(...) loop of ProcessGET() method is moved to separate method where it performs the same operation. But, as i said it helps in hiding/separating the these conditional statements.